# How to assign value to scope variable from a controller's function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, promise

My objective is to display a page while calculating the balance in the background and show that balance. I thought I'd try to isolate the balance into its own directive. So, I've created the following directive:

```html
app.directive('smBalanceInfo', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            //transclude: true,
            //replace: true,
           
            scope: {
                title: '@',

                calculateBalance: '&',

            },
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.balance = 0;              

                $scope.calculated = false;

                var getBalance = function () {

                    $scope.balance = $scope.calculateBalance();
                    $scope.calculated = true;
                };

                getBalance();
            }],
```

with this very simple html:

```html
{{title}}: <span ng-hide="calculated">Calculating...</span>
<span ng-show="calculated" ng-class="{'negative-amount': balance < 0}">{{balance| currency:""}}</span>
```

And in my form I put the following:

```html
 <div class="col-md-4" data-sm:balance-info title="@Labels.totalDueForAllInvoices" calculate-balance="getAccountBalance()"></div>
```

And the form's controller method getAccountBalance is the following:

```html
$scope.getAccountBalance = function () {
              var totalBalance = 0;
              if (!$scope.isNew) {
                  accountsService.getAccountBalance($scope.invoicesObject.accountNameHash).then(function (data) {
                      totalBalance = data.balance;

                      return totalBalance;
                  });
              }
              else { return totalBalance; }
          };
```

So, this is all good except for the fact that my directive variable balance is undefined and nothing is getting displayed even though when I trace it I see the value totalBalance calculated.

What should I change in the above to be able to get the value from controller's function back into the directive and more globally, have the behavior I want (e.g. form displayed while balance still calculated)?

Answer (score 1):

Your directive has an isolated scope and the balance variable are not visible from outside of it. Try to add the balance as scope variable of the directive

```
app.directive('smBalanceInfo', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            //transclude: true,
            //replace: true,

            scope: {
                title: '@',
                balance:'=',
                calculateBalance: '&',

            },
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.balance = 0;              

                $scope.calculated = false;

                var getBalance = function () {

                    $scope.balance = $scope.calculateBalance();
                    $scope.calculated = true;
                };

                getBalance();
            }],
```

Then in your html template link the directive balance variable to the controller scope balance adding attribute `balance="balance"` like:

```
<div class="col-md-4" data-sm:balance-info title="@Labels.totalDueForAllInvoices" balance="balance" calculate-balance="getAccountBalance()"></div>
```

See [Mastering the scope of directives](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/)

Answer (score 0):

I also solved that problem in the meantime. I made my directive very simple:

```html
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('sysMgrApp');

    app.directive('smBalanceInfo', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            //transclude: true,
            //replace: true,
           
            scope: {
                title: '@',
                calculated: '=',
                balance: '=',

            },
            
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/smBalanceInfo'
        };
    });

})();
```

And in the main controller I added at the end of the account loading method:

```html
          $rootScope.$broadcast('sm:focus');
                  $rootScope.$broadcast('accounts:accountLoaded');
              });

          };

          var getAccountBalance = function () {
              var totalBalance = 0;
              if (!$scope.isNew) {
                  accountsService.getAccountBalance($scope.currentAccount.acctNameHash).then(function (data) {
                      $scope.currentAccount.totalBalance = data.balance;
                      $scope.balanceCalculated = true;
                      return totalBalance;
                  });
              }
              else {
                  $scope.balanceCalculated = true;
                  return totalBalance;
              }
          };

          $scope.$on('accounts:accountLoaded', function (event) {
              getAccountBalance();
          });
```

So, now my account information is loaded, I see the 'Calculating' message and then the balance comes just fine.